# Malloc failed on ps4 development

Tags: c++, malloc

I get a malloc(180K) error in my program, so I commented them and write the code below in the same file. It still return a bad ptr. (I get it by breakpoint at return)

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *b = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1000000);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I suppose the issue is on my computer, so I open an other program on same condition (46% memory used), (I did not close the pre project), I write the same code in `main()` first, and the `malloc` returns normally.
What should be the issue?

PS: WINDOWS7 X64 (4G) I think it remain at least 1G memory，because the memory used showed in explorer is 46%.

Comment: The system can't find that much memory in one contiguous block.  When asking this type of question you need to provide more information about the environment, such as how much memory you think you have available and how you determined that.

Comment: This program ignores the return value of malloc and always returns success, so how do you know it failed?

Comment: You're allocating a megabyte, not a gigabyte.  It's pretty unlikely that your computer has less than a megabyte of free memory.

Comment: You can create a loop that allocates small memory blocks and executes until the allocation fails. Then you can repeat with bigger blocks. This will inform you about the memory available to your program (small blocks) and about block size that can be allocated (big blocks).

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to SCE, and get response that they had add some limit in play station 4 project. I must declare a global virable `size_t sceLibcHeapSize = 1*1024*1024*50;` to set up the heap, otherwise it's default value would be 64K or 256K?(I forget it..)